# Unable to launch IIS Express in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express, visual-studio-2017

Had a web application working in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 perfectly. I ported the project to Visual Studio 2017 RC and compiled successfully. When debugging the application IIS Express terminates after dumping the message below in the output pane of VS 2017 RC:

```
The program '[7896] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8488] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8488] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7896] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What's the solution to make the project running and debuggable?

Comment: What version of iis are you using? Is it below v10?

Comment: @AKADER The most recent IIS Express downloaded from MS website assuming it's v10.

Comment: I have a same problem in VS2017 15.0.0-RC.4+.26206.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case with Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition I tried following:

- Delete IISExpress config folder in Documents
- Delete hidden .vs in project root
- Restart Visual Studio 2017 and computer

nothing worked until I re-run Visualt Studio Installer and choose option "Repair". Then somehow everything started working.

Comment: The repair fixed the issue indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably missing `"commandName": "Project"` in your `launchSettings.json` file. 
I have described the issues I faced with porting to VS 2017 [here](http://adamsitnik.com/Porting-ASP-NET-Core-application-to-VS2017/)