# VS2017 in Windows 7 "An error occured attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express-10

Project properties -> Enable SSL : false (Off)

[image: Web API Project settings]

Selected "IIS Express" as debug option

"IIS 10.0 Express" already installed

Getting below error always

[image]

Can any one suggest a fix ?

Already tried below URLs, no hope still

[An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application. One or more error occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965442/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id-of-dotnet-exe-which-is)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43351447/2089963

Also tried uninstalling & installed IIS Express 10 back. Any help?

Environment : Windows 7(x64)
Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.4) + .net Core 2.0

Comment: Can you run Kestrel alone successfully? That error usually indicates `dotnet.exe` exited.

Comment: I don't have kestrel, do i need to install.? having IIS-10 only. Bcos the same code runs fine in Windows10, w/o Kestrel

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/a-closer-look-at-asp-net-core-execution-model-b3c332f6ed1

Comment: What happens if you execute "dotnet run" command from CMD in your project folder ?

Comment: for me dotnet run and ctrl f5 works, and only debugging fails

Comment: Finally Installing Windows-10 works for me

Answer (score 0):

Potential fix:

> Maybe you can try delete the .vs folder.

Copied from @snys98 answer to this post: [An error occurred attempting to determine the process id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294485/an-error-occurred-attempting-to-determine-the-process-id/42294686#42294686)

Sorry if you already tried that.