# An Error Occured Launching IIS Express - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

Suddenly After Updating My Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition from version 15.9.1 to 15.9.2 I am facing a Weird issue

[image]

I have tried many solution from other stack overflow post

[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544936/unable-to-launch-the-configured-visual-studio-development-web-server)

[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175554/unable-to-launch-iis-express-in-visual-studio-2017-rc)

But nothing seems to work out .

I did delete .vs folder , IIS Express Folder from My Documents , Restarted VS as admin , Restarted My PC , repaired VS also .

When I directly run IIS express after clicking on its application icon , than it run perfectly but with port 1500 , but not when run from VS

Is there any way to rollback to previous version?

Comment: not gonna work , had to clean up whole windows , Microsoft update are too frequent now a days and very unstable ,

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue(Unable to lunch IIS express) after update VS to 15.9.2 and I fix it by lunching repair from Visual Studio Installer.